# How can I make this repeat?

Tags: jquery, html

Jquery:

```
var picname = ["1.jpg"];
      var pics = 0;

      $("#pic").mouseenter(function() {

        $("#pic").fadeOut(300, function() { 
          $("#pic").attr("src", picname[pics]); 
          pics++;    
          if (pics > 2) {pics = 0;} 
          $("#pic").fadeIn(500); 
        });

      }); 



$("#pic").mouseleave(function() {

        $("#pic").fadeOut(300, function() { 
          $("#pic").attr("src", picname[pics]); 
          pics++;    
          if (pics > 2) {pics = 0;} 
          $("#pic").fadeIn(500); 
        });

  });
```

Html:

```
 <img id= 'pic' src="1.jpg"/>
```

I want to repeat itself for exemple when I put my mouse on that picture it changes and when I leave the mouse it become to normal and this repeats itself.

Comment: did you try the obvious `$("#pic").mouseleave()` yet?

Comment: please edit your question and post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried only mouseleave instead of mouseenter

Comment: well you need both...

Comment: yes after this i wrote the same but instead of mouseenter i put mouseleave

Comment: post in your question what you have tried please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to cycle between 2 pictures, you dont need the array with picture names. just do it like this:

```js
$("#pic").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#pic").fadeOut(300, function() {
    $("#pic").attr("src", "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/banana_clip_art_13734.jpg");
    $("#pic").fadeIn(500);
  });
});
$("#pic").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#pic").fadeOut(300, function() {
    $("#pic").attr("src", "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/banana_clip_art_13529.jpg");
    $("#pic").fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='pic' src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/banana_clip_art_13529.jpg" />
```